# Tidyverse solution for Counting nulls from multiple fields

Tags: r

I'm trying to summarize my data by counting the number of nulls and number of responses (values + `NA`) for 12 different columns. (renamed for this example)

Data:

```
my_df <- structure(list(SCR1 = c(100, 80.2, 70.3, 
90.1, 100, 100, 100, 100, 40.6, 80.2, 80.2, 90.1, 30.7, 100, 
80.2), SCR2 = c(75.25, 75.25, 75.25, 75.25, 75.25, 75.25, 
100, 100, 50.5, 50.5, 75.25, 50.5, 50.5, 100, 50.5), SCR3 = c(100, 
100, 100, 100, 75.25, 75.25, 100, 100, 100, 75.25, 100, 100, 
NA, 100, 75.25), SCR4 = c(100, 50.5, 
50.5, 75.25, 100, 75.25, 100, 100, 100, 75.25, 50.5, 100, 100, 
100, 75.25), SCR5 = c(100, 75.25, 50.5, 
75.25, 100, 75.25, 100, 100, 50.5, 75.25, 75.25, 75.25, 25.75, 
100, 75.25), SCR6 = c(100, 25.75, 50.5, 
75.25, 100, 75.25, 100, 100, 75.25, 75.25, 75.25, 100, 50.5, 
100, 50.5), SCR7 = c(75.25, 50.5, 75.25, 
100, 50.5, 75.25, 100, 100, 75.25, 50.5, 75.25, 100, 25.75, 100, 
75.25), SCR8 = c(75.25, 75.25, 50.5, 75.25, 
75.25, 75.25, 100, 100, 75.25, 75.25, 75.25, 75.25, 50.5, 100, 
75.25), SCR9 = c(50.5, NA, NA, 25.75, 100, NA, 
NA, NA, 100, NA, NA, NA, 75.25, NA, NA), SCR10 = c(25.75, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), SCR11 = c(100, 
75.25, 50.5, 75.25, 100, 75.25, 100, 100, 75.25, 75.25, 75.25, 
100, 50.5, 100, 50.5), SCR12 = c(75.25, 75.25, 
50.5, NA, 75.25, 75.25, 100, 100, 75.25, NA, 75.25, 75.25, 50.5, 
100, 50.5), ID = 1:15), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here I'd like to return the number of values and the number of `NA` and then the percent `NA`

I found a solution to count the number of `NA` but I'm struggling to add a 2nd/3rd column with count and percents.

`my_df %>%
  map_df(function(x) sum(is.na(x))) %>%
  gather(feature, num_nulls) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(num_nulls))`

How can I add counts and percent na? I'm trying to use the tidyverse and avoid using SQL.

Comment: what do you mean by `responses `?

Comment: `responses` = the number of values including NA. For this example each column has 15 `responses`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. The additional two columns could be created with an additional `mutate` statement:

```
my_df %>%
    map_df(function(x) sum(is.na(x))) %>%
    gather(feature, num_nulls) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(desc(num_nulls)) %>%
    mutate(num_responses = nrow(my_df) - num_nulls,
        percent = num_responses/nrow(my_df))
```